# Convert static fragment to view pager based fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following . I have a fragment on the left which is grid view of questions Q1,Q2 etc., If user clicks on Q1 on the right there is a fragment which shows the question details with 4 options. Now I want to implement view pager for the right hand side fragment. 
My main looks like -

Fragment 1
Fragment 2

For the grid i have an activity which instantiates the question list and I have another fragment to show the questions. 
Please can someone tell me how I can add a view pager only for the fragment on the right whilst using the existing logic .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add ViewPager to the layout of your Fragment2, either programmatically or using xml layout file.

If you wan't it to navigate through questions in Fragment1 and Fragment1 to react to it (by highlighting items) - you can broadcast an intent every time a page is flipped and handle it in Fragment1.

I'm not sure I understand what kind of problem you're having, can you provide more details?

Comment: Thanks! Its like this - I have logic implemented for everything and now Im trying to fit in the view pager now. My screen in landscape is divided into two fragments - on the left question numbers and on the right actual questions . I m using grid to display questions and clicking on a question number shows me question on the right. Now I want alternate navigation for questions - i.e. swiping . Swiping on the right fragment should navigate through questions . Hope I am clear . I have one main.xml with the two fragments, one main activity to load the fragments and two fragment classes.

Comment: So, yeah, seems like i understood you right the first time. Is my answer clear or do you need more details?